# Php Recursive Function Infinite loop Error

Tags: php

I am having a php recursive function to calculate nearest sale price. but i don't know why its run infinite time and throw error of maximum execution.

**Its look like below:**

```
 function getamazonsaleper($portal)
      {
          $cp = floatval($this->input->post('cp')); //user provided inputs
          $sp = floatval($this->input->post('sp')); //user provided input
          $gst = floatval($this->input->post('gst')); //user provided input
          $rfsp = floatval($this->input->post('rfsp')); //user provided input
          $mcp = (int)($this->input->post('mcp')); //user provided input
          $weight = floatval($this->input->post('weight')); //user provided input

          $output = $this->getsalepercent($cp,$sp,$gst,$rfsp,$mcp,$weight,$portal); 
          return $output;




      }
      function getsalepercent($cp,$sp,$gst,$rfsp,$mcp,$weight,$portal) //recursive funtion
      {

          $spcost = ((($sp/100)*$cp));
          $gstamount= (($spcost/(100+$gst))*$gst);
          $rfspamount= ($spcost*($rfsp/100));
          $mcpamount= ($cp*($mcp/100));

          $fixedfee=$this->getfixedfee($portal,$spcost);
          $weightfee=$this->getweightprice($portal,$weight);
          $totalcost=$fixedfee+$weightfee+$rfspamount;
          $gstinput=($totalcost*(18/100));
          $remittances = $spcost-$totalcost-$gstinput;
          $actualprofit= $remittances-$cp-$gstamount+$gstinput;
          $actualprofitpercent = ($actualprofit/$cp)*100;

          if( $actualprofitpercent >= $mcp)
          {
              return $sp;

          }elseif($actualprofitpercent < $mcp)
          {
              $newsp = (int)($sp+10) ;
              $this->getsalepercent($cp,$newsp,$gst,$rfsp,$mcp,$weight,$portal);

          }

      }
```

Can anybody tell me how can resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Edited :

**Perameters**

```
$cp=100;
$sp=200;
$mcp=20;
$weight=0.5;
$gst=28;
$rfsp=6.5;
```

Comment: Please provide the parameters values for `$cp`, `$sp`, etc. that results in an infinite loop.

Comment: you need more conditions to break the loop because `if( $actualprofitpercent >= $mcp)` never happens then loop never stops

Comment: The functions `getfixedfee()` and `getweightprice()` are missing.

Comment: You're recursive call to `$this->getsalepercent()` should be `return $this->getsalepercent()`

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeBoudreau . changing to return $this->getsalepercent() worked .

Answer (score 0):

First a couple of side notes:
- the way you use $gstinput it cancels itself out when you calculate $actualprofit (it's -$gstinput in $remittances which gets added to +$gstinput).
- $mcpamount seems to go completely unused in the code... I thought for a second you might vahe simply confused vars when doing the comparison, but of course for $cp = 100 it makes no difference.

Even so when I made a few calculations using the example values you gave for $sp = 200 (and growing by 10), I got:

Value of $actualprofit, which for $cp = 100 is also the value of $actualprofitpercent...

for $sp = 200:
43.25 - $fixedfee - $weightfee

for $sp = 210:
50.4125 - $fixedfee - $weightfee

for $sp = 220:
57.575 - $fixedfee - $weightfee

so for each $sp = $sp + 10 recursion the value of $actualprofitpercent (without taking into account $fixedfee and $weightfee) seems to grow by 7.1625.
The value of $weightfee should stay the same, but the value of $fixedfee depends on the value of $sp... Could it be that at each recursion getfixedfee() returns a value which grows faster than 7.1625?